# Marker.remove() is not working in google map, I want to remove the marker outside the radius?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

in my application I am using list of markers but when I tried to remove the marker its not removing the marker.

`Marker.remove()` is not working in google map, I want to remove the marker outside the radius.

Please help

My source code is given below :

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener
{ 
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleApp"; 

    private MapView mMapView; 
    private GoogleMap mMap; 
    private Bundle mBundle; 
    private static final String SERVICE_URL = "http://203.187.247.199/primevts/vtsservice.svc/data"; 
    JSONObject json = null; 
    JSONObject jsonobject = null; 
    JSONObject jsonobject1 =null;
    JSONObject jsonobject2 =null;
    JSONObject ja = null; 
    JSONArray jsonarray = null; 
    JSONArray jsonarray1 = null;
    JSONArray jsonarray2 = null;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog; 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist1; 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist11; 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist12; 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist; 
    List<Marker> markerList = new ArrayList<Marker>();
    private Timer timer;
    static String LONG = "Long"; 
    static String LAT = "Lat"; 
    ArrayList<String> ct; 
    public double latt = 0; 
    public double lng = 0; 
    public ArrayList<Integer> dLat; 
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    private Handler handler;
    public Marker marker;
    Marker stop = null;
    String RegistrationNo="";
    LatLng destination,source,destination2,center;
    Polyline polylin;
    String ime1,destname,routeid;
    GMapV2GetRouteDirection md;
    private HashMap<String, Marker> mMarkers = new HashMap<>();
    int value=1;
    // LatLngBounds values ; 
    double latitude, longitude,destlat,destlong,sourcelat,sourcelong,destlat2,destlong2; 
    String ime,reg,regi; 
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    CircleOptions circleOptions;
    Circle circle;
    // LatLng val; 
    float[] distance = new float[2];
    static HashMap<String, String> datas; 

    static HashMap<String, String> map; 
    String[] latlngvalues;
    //  LocationManager locman;
    Context context;
    View rootView;
    ImageView imageView1;
    TextView Address;
    public MapFragment() { 
    } 

    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_one, container, false); 


        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity()); 

        mMapView = (MapView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView); 
        Address=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.adressText);
        //imageView1=(ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        mMapView.onCreate(mBundle); 


        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity()); 

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) { 
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder() 
            .permitAll().build(); 
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
        } 
        new DownloadJSON().execute(); 
        setUpMapIfNeeded(rootView);
        new DestinationJSON().execute();
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                View v  = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);



                TextView markerLabel = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ime);
                TextView destiname=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.destname);
                TextView route=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.routeid);


                markerLabel.setText(regi);
                destiname.setText(destname);
                route.setText(routeid);
                Log.e("imeid", ""+ime1);
                return v;
            }

        });

        /* handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 new DownloadJSON().execute(); 
                    setUpMapIfNeeded(rootView); 

                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data Updated!!!! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Log.e("Data in Log", "");
            }
        }, 1000);
         */
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //mMap.clear();
                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data Updated!!!! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        new DownloadJSON().execute(); 
                        setUpMapIfNeeded(rootView); 
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 20000, 20000);




        /*LocationManager locman = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //locman.requestLocationUpdates(minTime, minDistance, criteria, intent);
        locman.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, this);*/
        return rootView; 
    } 

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded(View inflatedView) { 

        if (mMap == null) { 
            mMap = ((MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.mapView)).getMap(); 
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 

            Location myLocation = mMap.getMyLocation(); 
            if (mMap != null) {  
                //mMap.clear();

                mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCameraChange(final CameraPosition arg0) {
                        mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onMapLoaded() {
                                LatLng latLng= mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
                                double lat = latLng.latitude;
                                double lng = latLng.longitude;
                                Log.e("lati",""+lat);
                                Log.e("longi",""+lng);
                                Log.d("TAG", latLng.toString());
                                //mMap.clear();
                                if(circle!=null){
                                    circle.remove();
                                    //mMap.clear();
                                }



                                circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
                                circleOptions.center(latLng);
                                //circleOptions.fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                                circleOptions.radius(10000);
                                circleOptions.strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                                circle = mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
                                Log.e("",""+circle);
                                center = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;

                                new GetLocationAsync(center.latitude, center.longitude).execute();

                                /* geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());

                                try {
                                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
                                     String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
                                      Log.e("address",""+address);
                                        String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                                        Log.e("city",""+city);
                                        String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                                        Log.e("state",""+state);
                                        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                                        Log.e("contry",""+country);
                                        String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                                        Log.e("postalcode",""+postalCode);
                                        String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
                                        Log.e("knownName",""+knownName);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5


                                //Toast.makeText(this, latLng.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }*/



                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(stop!=null){
                            mMap.clear();
                        }




                        regi=arg0.getTitle().toString();
                        Log.e("aaa", ""+regi);
                        JSONPost jsonpost= new JSONPost();

                        ja=jsonpost.datewise(regi);
                        Log.e("Home_details..", "" + ja);
                        //  new DownloadJSON2().execute();



                        try
                        {

                            arraylist11 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                            arraylist12 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                            jsonarray = ja.getJSONArray("Routeinbus");

                            for (int i = 0; i <jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                json = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.e("G>>>>>>>>>>>", "" + json);
                                // Retrive JSON Objects
                                // map.put("flatID", jsonobject.getString("flatID"));
                                map.put("FromLat", json.getString("FromLat"));

                                map.put("FromLong", json.getString("FromLong"));
                                sourcelat = json.getDouble("FromLat"); 
                                sourcelong=json.getDouble("FromLong");
                                source=new LatLng(sourcelat, sourcelong);
                                map.put("Fromaddress", json.getString("Fromaddress"));
                                map.put("ToLat", json.getString("ToLat"));
                                map.put("ToLong", json.getString("ToLong"));
                                routeid=json.getString("RouteID");
                                destname=json.getString("Toaddress");
                                destlat2=json.getDouble("ToLat");
                                destlong2=json.getDouble("ToLong");
                                destination2=new LatLng(destlat2, destlong2);
                                jsonarray1 = json.getJSONArray("Routes");
                                Log.d("Hbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", "" + jsonarray1);

                                for (int j = 0; j <jsonarray1.length(); j++) {


                                    jsonobject1 = jsonarray1.getJSONObject(j);
                                    jsonarray2=jsonobject1.getJSONArray("stages");
                                    Log.d("jsonarray2", "" + jsonarray2);

                                    for(int k=0;k<jsonarray2.length();k++)
                                    {
                                        jsonobject2 =jsonarray2.getJSONObject(k);
                                        HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                        map1.put("Lat",jsonobject2.getString("Lat"));

                                        Log.d("Hbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", "" + jsonobject2.getString("Lat"));
                                        map1.put("Long",jsonobject2.getString("Long"));
                                        map1.put("StopName", jsonobject2.getString("StopName"));
                                        Log.d("Hbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", "" + jsonobject2.getString("Long"));
                                        //      map1.put("LiveLongitude",jsonobject1.getString("LiveLongitude"));

                                        //       Log.d("Hbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", "" + jsonobject1.getString("LiveLongitude"));


                                        arraylist12.add(map1);

                                        Log.e("arraylist12", ""+arraylist12);

                                        /*if(polylin!=null){
                            polylin.remove();
                        }
                        if(marker!=null){
                            marker.remove();
                        }

                        md = new GMapV2GetRouteDirection();
                        Document doc = md.getDocument(source, destination2,
                                GMapV2GetRouteDirection.MODE_DRIVING);
                        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);
                        PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(10).color(
                                Color.CYAN);

                        for (int a = 0; a < directionPoint.size(); a++) {
                            rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(a));
                        }

                        polylin = mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);*/
                                        //marker=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destination2).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory .fromResource(R.drawable.bustour)));


                                        for (int m = 0; m < arraylist12.size(); m++)
                                        { 

                                            final LatLng stopposition = new LatLng(Double .parseDouble(arraylist12.get(m).get("Lat")),Double.parseDouble(arraylist12.get(m).get("Long"))); 
                                            Log.e("position", ""+stopposition);                             
                                            String stopname = arraylist12.get(m).get("StopName");
                                            Log.e("markcheck",""+stopname);


                                                 final MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(stopposition).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory .fromResource(R.drawable.greenbus)).title(stopname); 
                                                    //mMap.addMarker(options); 
                                                 stop=mMap.addMarker(options);
                                        }



                                    }
                                }
                                arraylist11.add(map);
                                Log.e("arraylist11",""+arraylist11);

                            } 

                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            String result = "Error";
                        }

                        return false;
                    }


                });
                // setUpMap(); 
                mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() { 

                    @Override 
                    public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) { 

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

                        final LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder(); 
                        //  mMap.clear();
                    /*  if(marker!=null){
                            marker.remove();
                        }*/
                        for (int i = 0; i < arraylist1.size(); i++) { 
                            final LatLng position = new LatLng(Double 
                                    .parseDouble(arraylist1.get(i).get("Latitude")), 
                                    Double.parseDouble(arraylist1.get(i).get( 
                                            "Longitude"))); 
                            Double lati=Double.parseDouble(arraylist1.get(i).get("Latitude"));
                            Double longi=Double.parseDouble(arraylist1.get(i).get("Longitude"));
                            //  Log.e("doublelati",""+lati);
                            //  Log.e("doublelongi",""+longi);
                            ime1 = arraylist1.get(i).get("RegistrationNo");
                            final MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions() 
                            .position(position); 
                            //mMap.addMarker(options); 

                            //marker=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory .fromResource(R.drawable.buspng)));
                            // mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());
                            //marker.showInfoWindow();
                            try 
                            {
                                Location.distanceBetween(lati,longi,circle.getCenter().latitude, circle.getCenter().longitude, distance);

                                if ( distance[0] <= circle.getRadius())
                                {

                                    marker=mMap.addMarker(options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory .fromResource(R.drawable.whitebus)).anchor(0.0f, 1.0f).title(ime1));
                                    // Inside The Circle
                                }
                                else 
                                {
                                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "currently no buses available at this location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    /*  if(marker!=null)
                                    {
                                            marker.remove();
                                    }*/
                                    // Outside The Circle
                                    marker.remove();
                                }
                            }catch (Exception e){

                            }
                            //options.title(ime1);
                            builder.include(position); 

                        } if(value==1){
                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0 
                                    .getLongitude()); 

                            //mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 

                            //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(newLatLnglatLng)); 
                            // mMap.setOnMapClickListener(null); 

                            //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(9)); 
                            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(latLng)      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
                            .zoom(10)                   // Sets the zoom
                            .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
                            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                            value++;
                        }
                    }
                }); 
            } 
        }
    }



    private class DestinationJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 
        String result=""; 
        @Override 
        protected void onPreExecute() { 
            super.onPreExecute(); 
        }

        @Override 
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
            try { 
                arraylist1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 

                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser(); 
                String result = ""; 

                json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/NJMZPNSi"); 

                try { 
                    arraylist1.clear(); 

                    jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("SingleIMEs"); 
                    Log.d("Haaaaaaaaaaaa", "" + json); 
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) { 
                        Log.d("H11111111111111111111111111", 
                                "" + jsonarray.length()); 
                        map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
                        json = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i); 

                        destlat = json.getDouble("Latitude"); 
                        destlong = json.getDouble("Longitude"); 
                        ime = json.getString("IME");
                        //reg=json.getString("RegistrationNo");
                        map.put("Latitude", json.getString("Latitude")); 
                        Log.e("CHECKLAT",""+json.getString("Latitude") );
                        map.put("Longitude", json.getString("Longitude")); 
                        Log.e("CHECKLONG",""+json.getString("Longitude") );
                        //map.put("RegistrationNo", json.getString("RegistrationNo"));
                        map.put("IME", json.getString("IME"));
                        destination=new LatLng(destlat, destlong);                  } 

                } catch (JSONException e) { 
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString()); 
                    result="Error"; 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
            }catch(Exception e){ 
                result="Error"; 
            } 

            return null; 
        } 

        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) { 

            // mProgressDialog.dismiss(); 

        } 
    }
    private class GetLocationAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        // boolean duplicateResponse;
        double x, y;
        StringBuilder str;

        public GetLocationAsync(double latitude, double longitude) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            x = latitude;
            y = longitude;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Address.setText(" Getting location ");
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try { geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.ENGLISH);
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(x, y, 1);
            str = new StringBuilder();
            if (geocoder.isPresent()) {
                Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);

                String localityString = returnAddress.getLocality();
                String city = returnAddress.getCountryName();
                String region_code = returnAddress.getCountryCode();
                String zipcode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();

                str.append(localityString + "");
                str.append(city + "" + region_code + "");
                str.append(zipcode + "");

            } else {
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                Address.setText(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                        + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 
        String result=""; 
        @Override 
        protected void onPreExecute() { 
            super.onPreExecute(); 
        }

        @Override 
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
            try { 
                arraylist1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 

                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser(); 
                String result = ""; 

                json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(SERVICE_URL); 

                try { 
                    arraylist1.clear(); 

                    jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("SingleIMEs"); 
                    Log.d("Haaaaaaaaaaaa", "" + json); 
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) { 
                        Log.d("H11111111111111111111111111", 
                                "" + jsonarray.length()); 
                        map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
                        json = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i); 

                        latitude = json.getDouble("Latitude"); 
                        longitude = json.getDouble("Longitude"); 
                        ime = json.getString("IME");
                        reg=json.getString("RegistrationNo");
                        map.put("Latitude", json.getString("Latitude")); 
                        Log.e("CHECKLAT",""+json.getString("Latitude") );
                        map.put("Longitude", json.getString("Longitude")); 
                        Log.e("CHECKLONG",""+json.getString("Longitude") );
                        map.put("RegistrationNo", json.getString("RegistrationNo"));
                        map.put("IME", json.getString("IME"));
                        arraylist1.add(map); 
                        //Log.e("arraylist1", ""+arraylist1);
                    } 

                } catch (JSONException e) { 
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString()); 
                    result="Error"; 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
            }catch(Exception e){ 
                result="Error"; 
            } 

            return null; 
        } 

        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) { 

            // mProgressDialog.dismiss(); 

        } 
    } 


    @Override 
    public void onResume() { 
        super.onResume(); 
        mMapView.onResume(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onPause() { 
        super.onPause(); 
        mMapView.onPause(); 
    } 
    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override 
    public void onDestroy() { 
        mMapView.onDestroy(); 
        super.onDestroy(); 
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /* Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onLocationUpdated!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("onLocationUpdated!!!","");
        new DownloadJSON().execute(); 
        setUpMapIfNeeded(rootView);*/

    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    } {




    }



    }
```

Comment: do you want to remove all the markers on map?

Comment: @AlokNair No I have two set of markers i want to remove the one set of markers but I don't want to clear the map want to remove the set of markers and add the new one  please check my code .

Comment: Make sure that you catched all the `Marker set` outside of your circle.